# Not able to connect mongodb by terminal using authentication data

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, terminal, mongo-shell

Mongo version 5.0.2.
Ubuntu 20.0

I have enabled security for MongoDB connection in my local host.
I am trying to connect my localhost MongoDB using authentication details by below commands

`mongo admin -u ADMIN_1234 -p "PASSWORD_1234" -host localhost:27017`

`mongo admin -u ADMIN_1234 -p "PASSWORD_1234" -host 127.0.0.1:27017`

`mongo admin -u ADMIN_1234 -p "PASSWORD_1234"`

`mongo admin -u ADMIN_1234 -p PASSWORD_1234 -host localhost:27017`

`mongo admin -u ADMIN_1234 -p PASSWORD_1234 -host 127.0.0.1:27017`

`mongo admin -u ADMIN_1234 -p PASSWORD_1234`

but below error, I am getting for all the above commands. not able to connect to mongodb

```
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Comment: Did you (re-)start your mongod after authentication was enabled? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User either `-u` or `--username`. For `host` you have only long version, i.e. `-h` does not exist, it is used for "help". Use one of these ones (I prefer `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1`):

```
mongo -u ADMIN_1234 -p PASSWORD_1234 localhost:27017/admin
mongo -u ADMIN_1234 -p PASSWORD_1234 --authenticationDatabase admin localhost:27017
mongo -u ADMIN_1234 -p PASSWORD_1234 --host localhost --authenticationDatabase admin 
mongo -u ADMIN_1234 -p PASSWORD_1234 --host localhost --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

or use the connection string URI

```
mongo "mongodb://ADMIN_1234:PASSWORD_1234@localhost:27017/admin"
```